# React-router-dom - Redirect on route doesn't activate new route

Tags: react-router-v4

In my App component I have:

```
 <Switch>                                         
         <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/en"/> }
        />
          <Route path="/:lang(en|sv|fr)" component={Master} />
         <Route component={PageNotFound} />
 </Switch>
```

If I go to `mysite.com/en`, the path successfully matches the Route which activates the Master component.

But if I go to the main domain ("/"), the url redirects to `mysite.com/en`, but the component Master is not activated, so nothing renders. Why?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED :**

This is working for me. You can try this.

```
    <Switch>                                         
             <Route
                 path="/:lang"
                 render={(props) => {
                    if (['en', 'sv', 'fr'].includes(props.match.params.lang)) {
                        return <Master {...props}/>;
                    }

                    return <PageNotFound/>;
                }}
             />
             <Redirect exact={true} from="/" to="/en" />
             <Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} />
     </Switch>
```